# Why does decoding bitmap with inBitmap always get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: P ro blem decoding into existing bitmap

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I am using inBitmap to load bitmap on android3+. But I always get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem decoding into existing bitmap.`

In LruCache's `entryMoved()` function: I use `reusableBitmaps.add(new SoftReference<Bitmap>(oldValue.getBitmap()));` to keep bitmap.

and next time to load bitmap:
I use iterator on reusableBitmaps to find which one I can use for inBitmap,
I use iterator to find which one, just like managing memory on official developer website.

But unfortunately, failed always, logcat shows `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem decoding into existing bitmap.`

Anyone can give me a sample or tutorial?

Comment: any one can help me please?

Comment: i also keep getting it, even though i've followed the tutorial here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsQet4nBVi8

Answer (score 10):

I fixed this using:

```
options.inSampleSize = 1;
```

This is a tip from the video mentioned at the second comment to the question.

Comment: This does not seem to be necessary on new phones (lollipop and up), but its omission is a problem on older phones

Comment: I wasn't aware of that - thanks. Docs say that KITKAT+ silently ignores this. So it's safe to keep this in, if minSdk<KITKAT

Answer (score 0):

Bitmaps are immutable as far as I can reason from the Bitmap api. The Bitmap class does not have a public constructor. To create one you have to specify the width and the height of the bitmap to one of the `createBitmap` methods.. So you cannot reuse a Bitmap instance.

But, just in case I am wrong, I guess the error will still be related with the fact that the bitmap holds the width and the height of the bitmap, which determines the size of the byte buffer used to decode the bitmap.

If you're decoding images of different resolutions into the same bitmap, this will most probably cause errors.

To troubleshoot try your very own same code to decode images of exactly the same width and exactly the same height. If your error goes away then my theory is correct and you need to cater for image sizes when it comes to reusable Bitmaps.

I am also interested in the result, so if you can post your findings that's be great.

Cheers